# How to skip some divs to search in context?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example I have the following HTML structure :

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="field-container">...</div>
   <div class="field-container">...</div>
   <div class="field-container">...</div>
   <div class="field-container-with-details">
      <div class="details">...</div>
      <div class="details">...</div>
      <div class="details">...</div>
      <div class="details-to-skip">...</div>
      <div class="details-to-skip">...</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to find all `inputs` in class `.container` except `inputs` that are in classes `.details-to-skip`.

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can [not-selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector)

```
$('.container input:not(.details-to-skip input)')
```

or .not()

```
$('.container input').not('.details-to-skip input')
```

---

```js
$('.container input:not(.details-to-skip input)').after('<span>before</span>');

$('.container input:not(.details-to-skip input)').val('selected')
```

```css
.field-container-with-details > div {
  padding: 5px;
}
.field-container-with-details > .details {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.field-container-with-details > .details-to-skip {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="field-container"></div>
  <div class="field-container">...</div>
  <div class="field-container">...</div>
  <div class="field-container-with-details">
    <div class="details">
      <input />
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <input />
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <input />
    </div>
    <div class="details-to-skip">
      <input />
    </div>
    <div class="details-to-skip">
      <div>
        <input />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your link is incorrect. Please update it to this http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/ or what you want? And does `:not` or `.not()` supported `IE8`?

Comment: @demo fixed... both are supported in IE8(not the [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#Browser_compatibility) css selector) - jQuery takes care of it

Comment: +1: This very cleverly uses an ancestor-descendant selector applied to descendants (which I did not realise would even work). Thanks for teaching me something new :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()`. Try this:

```
var $inputs = $('.container input').filter(function() {
    return $(this).closest('.details-to-skip').length == 0;
});
```

The `$inputs` variable will now contain a collection of all the inputs that are not contained within those divs.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$('.container div:not(.details-to-skip) > input')
```

Comment: Your example still includes all inputs as they are also descendants of `div` with `class=field-container-with-details`: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/z8cqx8kq/2/

Comment: I have removed my down-vote, now that you answer *looks exactly like mine*, so it must work :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately some answers are incorrectly selecting the inputs where any parent has `.details-to-skip`.

They tend to *re-include* the inputs as they are also descendants of the `div` with `class="field-container-with-details"`

The filter needs to be more specific:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/z8cqx8kq/1/

e.g.

```
$('.container div:not(.details-to-skip) > input');
```

Note: this will ony work if the inputs are direct children of the `div`.

- *Rory's answer is actually the most robust as it looks for an ancestor of each input with that class.*
- Arun P Johny's answer works as if by magic! It applies an ancestor-descendant relationship selector to a descendant (which I did not know would work - until today). Well done Arun :)